# Deleting a substring from a data frame Python

Tags: python, pandas

Hi guys I am new in Python and I would like to delete some characters from a row in a dataframe. The issue is that I have several countries and all of them have different information between parenthesis, so I have tried replace and some wildcards, but haven't worked at all.

---

Column 1
Country (Other info)

and would like to get just:

---

Column 1
Country

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***option 1***
replace in `Column 1`

```
df['Column 1'].str.replace(r'\s*\(.*\)', '')

0    Country
Name: Column 1, dtype: object
```

***option 2***
get the whole `df`

```
df.stack().str.replace(r'\s*\(.*\)', '').unstack()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using [.str.split()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) method:

DF:

```
In [29]: df
Out[29]:
                                  Column1
0                    Country (Other info)
1  Yet another country (yet another info)
```

Solution:

```
In [30]: df.Column1.str.split(r'\s*\(').str[0]
Out[30]:
0                Country
1    Yet another country
Name: Column1, dtype: object
```